# isHighlighted called multiple times on UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have subclassed `UIButton` and want to call a delegate method just once when the button goes into the highlighted state and call it again just once when it goes into the unhighlighted state:

```
override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            if isHighlighted {
                delegate?.buttonHighlightStateDidChange(highlighted: true)
            } else {
                delegate?.buttonHighlightStateDidChange(highlighted: false)
            }
        }
    }
```

However when I touch down on the button it seems that didSet is getting repeatedly called. What am I doing wrong here? How can I call the delegate method just once?

Comment: Not the answer but kill the if: delegate?.buttonHighlightStateDidChange(highlighted: isHighlighted) Also is the delegate doing anything with the button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend against using your subclass in this way. `UIControl` has a builtin mechanism for getting callbacks in response to control events:

```
func registerActions(for button: UIButton) {
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyClass.buttonIsHighlighted(sender:)), for: .touchDown)

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyClass.buttonIsUnHighlighted(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyClass.buttonIsUnHighlighted(sender:)), for: .touchUpOutside)
}

func buttonIsHighlighted(sender: UIButton) {
    // highlighted
}

func buttonIsUnHighlighted(sender: UIButton) {
    // unhighlighted
}
```

Comment: Awesome, forgot about this. Much easier now. thanks!